# how to repeat columns according to row data change in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Sql-server this is my table data

```
Companyname  Qty  Amount   tax
A             1      2      2
A             2      4      2
B             1      2      3
C             1      2      2
C             3      2      2
```

this is my excepted output.

```
        A                  B                C
Qty  Amount   tax | Qty  Amount   tax  | Qty  Amount   tax
3       6      4     1       2     3      4      4      4
```

company can be increase

Comment: All in one row? Not one row per company?

Comment: select companyname, sum(qty) as quantity , sum(amount) as amount, sum(tax) as tax from tablename group by companyname.......this query should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CompanyName + Col)
                                    FROM    T
                                            CROSS JOIN 
                                            (   VALUES 
                                                    ('_Qty'), 
                                                    ('_Amount'), 
                                                    ('_Tax')
                                            ) c (col)
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    '   SELECT  *
        FROM    (   SELECT  [Col] = CompanyName + ''_'' + col,
                            Value
                    FROM    T
                            UNPIVOT
                            (   Value
                                FOR Col IN ([Qty], [Amount], [Tax])
                            ) Upvt
                ) t
                PIVOT
                (   SUM(Value)
                    FOR [Col] IN (' + @cols + ')
                ) pvt;'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cdd55/3)**

However my advice would be don't use this. Handle pivoting data like this on the application side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per company, it's a simple `GROUP BY`;

```
SELECT Companyname, SUM(Qty) Qty, SUM(Amount) Amount, SUM(tax) tax
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Companyname
```

If you really want it all in one row as your expected output seems to indicate, it'll most likely require dynamic SQL, especially if you want the company name to be a line above the column names. That would make your query *significantly* more complex.